Solving a numerical equation with NSolve or FindRoot for a function depending on two variables, one of which should take continuous values
I am sorry to bother you with what I think it might be a trivial question but I am kinda new to the use of Mathematica in order to solve equations, differential equations and such; I am still trying to learn.
Some context: the final aim is to create a plot with the thermal cross-section for WIMPs on the y-axis and the Dark Matter particle mass on the x-axis, having fixed the relic abundance to 0.12 (the experimental value).
What I expect to appear is a "line" which remains constant for a thermal cross-section of 10^(-26) cm^3/s (equivalent to 10^-9 GeV^-2) and then it decreases a bit in value for higher masses.
My starting point was the following relation:

With Mathematica I tried different tecniques, from FindRoot to NSolve but I do not understand what is going wrong.
Moreover, I would like to find the numerical solution of the thermal cross-section with the mass running, while all I have found is that I can create a set of masses with defined step, which is not exactly what I am looking for.
I tried to look it up but I didn't find anything helpful.
Thank you in advance for the patience and the help, I really appreciate it.
Here is the code:
(*Parameters*)
Mpl = 1.220890*10^19;
h = 0.674;
rhoC = 1.053672*10^(-5); (*critical energy density, GeV/cm^3*)
s0 = 2891.2;(*cm^-3*)

(*The following functions are H(z_fo) and s(z_fo)*)
s[ms_, sigma_] = Simplify[(2 \[Pi]^2)/45 gsT[T] T^3 /. T -> ms/Log[ms*sigma*Mpl]](*GeV^3*);
H[ms_, sigma_] = Simplify[Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/90 gT[T] ] T^2/Mpl /. T -> ms/Log[ms*sigma*Mpl]](*GeV*);

(*Here I report the first try with NSolve*)
Yfo[ms_, sigma_] = H[ms, sigma]/(s[ms, sigma]*sigma);
Omega[ms_, sigma_] = (ms*Yfo[ms, sigma]*s0)/(rhoC/(h^2));

sol = NSolve[{Omega[ms, sigma] == 0.12, ms > 1 && ms < 10^5,sigma > 10^-9 && sigma < 10^2}, {ms, sigma}]; 
(*Here the error given is: NSolve::ivar: 200 is not a valid variable.*)

(*Second try with FindRoot*)
solSigma[ms_] = FindRoot[Omega[ms, sigma] == 0.12, {sigma, 1*10^-10, 1*10^2}];
(*Error: FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-0.12+Omega[ms,1.*10^-10]} is not a list
of numbers with dimensions {1} at {sigma} = {1.*10^-10}.*)

where gT[T] and gsT[T] are the energy density and entropy degrees of freedom, which I interpolated starting from some data (these shouldn't give any problem since I have already used and checked them while doing another code):
gT = Interpolation[Table[{Teff[[i]], geff[[i]]}, {i, Length[Teff]}]];
gsT = Interpolation[Table[{Teff[[i]], gs[[i]]}, {i, Length[Teff]}]];

Thanks again and I am sorry in advance for the roughness of my code.

gT and gsT are not definied ?

@MariuszIwaniuk yes, they are defined. At the end of the question I have reported the part of code regarding them. They are the result of an interpolation from some data (geff or gs, Teff) which come from a file (which I haven't reported since it isn't relevant for the main code). Thank you for asking.

In -0.12+Omega[ms,1.*10^-10], the variable ms does not have a numerical value. So FindRoot will not be able to find a numerical root. Perhaps define like ClearAll[solSigma]; solSigma[ms_?NumericQ] := FindRoot...

You appear to be asking for a symbolic solution for sigma as a function of ms.  I am confident that none exists.  So, obtain a table of sigma for selected values of ms and plot the resulting List using `ListPlot..

@bbgodfrey, you are right. What I was trying to do isn't possible. I'll try with what you are suggesting. Thank you very much for your answer!
